# Linux cp command not working from within Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash, sh, processbuilder, cp

I'm trying to copy an image file and set it as background using Java ProcessBuilder to run a shell script on Ubuntu.

When running the script myself from terminal, it executes as expected with no problem.

i.e.     ./changeBG.sh "jpg"

However, when running from inside Java I get output saying the process has finished, but upon checking the file manager I see that the cp never goes through and I end up with a black background when it runs the next command to change background.

Clues as to why cp isn't happening would be highly appreciated.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /home/$USER/Pictures/Wallpapers

/bin/cp -rf ./images/newimage.$1 
/home/$USER/Pictures/Wallpapers/background.$1

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/$USER/Pictures/Wallpapers/background.$1"

echo done
```

Java code:

```
try {

                String cmd= "./changeBG.sh \"" + currentIMGext + "\"" ;
                System.out.println(cmd);
                ProcessBuilder bd = new ProcessBuilder(cmd.split(" "));

                Process ps = bd.start();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ps.getInputStream()));
                String currentLine;

                while (true) {
                    currentLine = br.readLine();
                    if (currentLine == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println(currentLine);
                }

            } catch (Exception e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Java output:

```
./changeBG.sh "jpg"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding literal quotes as if you were a human writing commands in a shell. There's no human and no shell, so quotes don't enter into it. Just use

```
ProcessBuilder bd = new ProcessBuilder("./changeBG.sh", currentIMGext);
```

Comment: Fantastically explained, can't believe I didn't spot this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your file "./changeBG.sh" is not an executable in the sense of the operation system, rather it is just a text file interpreted by `bash`. So you should use `/bin/bash path/to/changeBG.sh args` for your String `cmd`.

Check with Posix' [exec(3)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/exec.html)

Comment: As long as it has a shebang and `+x`, it's an executable in the OS sense